# Two views of the same data in Google Sheets?

Tags: google-sheets

Is it possible to create two views of the same data in Google Sheets? Say you have a list of students and which teacher they have. Can you get a view that sorts by teacher, then student plus a view that sorts by student name, where both are driven by the same data? I'm trying to accomplish something similar to that example without having multiple copies of the original data set.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

More than two, if you want, but on a computer. [See](https://sites.google.com/a/york.ac.uk/workingwithdata/google-sheets/filter-views).

> [Sort and filter your data](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3540681?co=GENIE.Platform%3DDesktop&hl=en)
>
> You can sort and filter data in Google Sheets to organize and analyze
>   it.
>
> Note: Filter views are only available on a computer. See the [FILTER](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3093197) article for info about the function.
>
> Sort your data
>
> ```
> On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> Highlight the group of cells you'd like to sort.
> To select the entire sheet, click the top left corner of the sheet.
> Click Data and then Sort range.
> If your columns have titles, click Data has header row.
> Select the column you'd like to be sorted first and whether you would like  
> that column sorted in ascending or descending order. This also sorts numbers.
> Click +Add another sort column to add another sorting rule.
> Sorting will be done according to the order of your rules.
> To delete a rule, click Close Close.
> Click Sort. Your range will be sorted.
> ```
>
> Filter your data
>
> To see and analyze data in a spreadsheet, use filters. Filters let you
>   hide data that you don’t want to see. You’ll still be able to see all
>   your data when you turn the filter off. Filters vs. filter views
>
> Both filters and filter views help you analyze a set of data in a
>   spreadsheet.
>
> Filters can be useful if:
>
> ```
> You want everyone viewing your spreadsheet to see a specific filter when they open it.
> You want your data to stay sorted after using the filter.
> ```
>
> Filter views can be useful if:
>
> ```
> You want to save multiple views.
> You want to name your view.
> You want others to be able to view the data differently.
> ```
>
> Since filter views need to be turned on by each person viewing a
>   spreadsheet, each person can view a different filter view at the same
>   time.
>       You want to share different filters with people. You can send different filter view links to different people so everyone will see
>   the most relevant information for them.
>       You want to make a copy or create another view with similar rules.
>       You don't have edit access to a spreadsheet and still want to filter or sort. In this case, a temporary filter view will be created.
>
> Note: You can import and export filters, but not filter views. Use
>   filters in a spreadsheet
>
> To temporarily hide data in a spreadsheet, add a filter.
>
> Note: When you add a filter, anyone with access to your spreadsheet
>   will see the filter too. Anyone with permission to edit your
>   spreadsheet will be able to change the filter. Filter your data
>
> To filter your data:
>
> ```
> On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> Select a range of cells.
> Click Data and then Filter.
> To see filter options, go to the top of the range and click Filter Filter.
> ```
>
> Filter by condition:
>   Choose from a list of conditions or write your own. For example, if the cell is empty, if data is less than a
>   certain number, or if the text contains a certain letter or phrase.
>   Filter by values:
>   Uncheck any data points that you want to hide and click OK. If you want to choose all data points, click Select
>   all. You can also uncheck all data points, by clicking Clear.
>           Search: Search for data points by typing in the search box. For example, typing "P" will shorten your list to just the names that
>   start with P.
>       To turn the filter off, click Data and then Turn off filter.
>
> Sort your data while it’s filtered
>
> ```
> You can sort data with a filter turned on.
> When you sort your data, only the data in the filtered range will be sorted.
> You’ll see a green border around the cells in the filtered range.
> ```
>
> Create, name, and save a filter view
>
> Use a filter view when:
>
> ```
> You want to save your filter and use it later.
> You don't want to disrupt others' view of the data.
> You want to share a link to a specific filter with others.
> You can’t edit a spreadsheet, but you want to filter or sort data.
> ```
>
> Create, save, or delete a filter view
>
> ```
> On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> Click Data and then Filter views and then Create new filter view.
> Sort and filter the data.
> To close your filter view, go to the top right and click Close Close.
> Your filter view is saved automatically.
> ```
>
> To delete or duplicate a filter view go to the top right and click
>   Settings Settings and then Delete or Duplicate. Rename a filter view
>
> ```
> On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> Click Data and then Filter views.
> Select a filter view.
> Click the filter view name in the top left of the black bar and type the new name.
> Press Enter.
> ```
>
> See an existing filter view
>
> ```
> On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> Click Data and then Filter views.
> Select a filter view.
> Your filter will be applied to the spreadsheet.
> To close your filter view, go to the top right and click Close Close.
> ```
>
> Save a filter as a filter view
>
> ```
> On your computer, open a spreadsheet in Google Sheets.
> Apply a filter.
> Click Data and then Filter views and then Save as filter view.
> ```
>
> Use filter view with "view only" access
>
> If you have permission to view a spreadsheet but not edit it, you can
>   still use filter views:
>
> ```
> To apply existing filter views, click Data and then Filter views.
> ```
>
> You can create a temporary filter view that only you can use. Because you don’t have "edit" access to the spreadsheet, the filter
>   view won't be saved.
>       Only users with permission to edit a spreadsheet can create filter views that anyone viewing the spreadsheet can use.

Comment: I think this is what I'm looking for, thanks. Nice link to the example sheet too.

Comment: Hmm actually I need more of a permanent filter view where the first sheet is the dataset and a couple of more sheets show difference sortings of the data...

Comment: Yeah, but can I associate a filter view with a copy of the data on another sheet?